# What are some settlements in Greece circa 2000 BCE - 1900 BCE?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-greece, bronze-age

While looking at some data for a game I was working on set in 2000 BCE, I had the big problem: what are some ancient Greek settlements from **between 2000 BCE and 1900 BCE?**

The Minoans at the time had just integrated with the Cyclades and most historic records had to be found via archaeological evidence.

Comment: 2000 BCE is too early for the ancient Greek city states. I'd recommend 1400 BC for the beginning of Mycenean Greece (see [this map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycenaean_Greece#/media/File:Path3959-83.png)).

Comment: @Brasidas? Well, what important settlements at the time existed circa 2000 BCE to 1900 BCE? Outside the Minoan Civilisation?

Comment: Appears you want the Middle Helladic period for mainland Greece and Cycladic for Aegean.  Some info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helladic_period and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycladic_culture

Comment: Edited for clarity and format.  Your last clause didn't make sense, so I tried to turn it into a sentence.  If that isn't what you meant, please edit again to clarify what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Lerna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerna)?  Also [this](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~prehistory/aegean/?page_id=652).  For population estimates (and social complexity) of Lerna and other cities at a somewhat earlier date, look at [Social Complexity and Population:  A Study in the Early Bronze Age Aegean](http://www.pia-journal.co.uk/articles/abstract/10.5334/pia.225/).

Comment: Awesome link to that lecture.  +1 if you'll summarize or highlight a few points from the cited "social complexity" work.

Answer (score 0):

Manika, Thebes and Tiryns appear to have been some of the largest settlements of the Helladic period. Lerna is also notable, mostly for the so-called House of Tiles rather than for its size.
The vast majority of settlements in this period are small villages and hamlets. We don't know the names of these settlements. Often they are simply named after the nearest modern settlement.